# How can I see long stack traces in my tests?

Tags: mocha.js, bluebird

When I run my test suite, failures will only include short stack traces.

bluebird supports generating [long stack traces](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html#long-stack-traces), but when I try to enable them, I suddenly get *only* the error message and no stack trace at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the full, long stack trace, you need to *both* enable long stack traces, as mentioned in the documentation *and* run mocha with `--full-trace`.

For example:

```
$ BLUEBIRD_DEBUG=1 mocha --full-trace
```